# Blockcypher-python UnicodeError("label too long")

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitcoin, blockcypher

I'm having a nasty issue with [Blockcypher for Python](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python).
A simple snippet code

```
import sys
from blockcypher import get_address_overview

print(sys.version)
print(sys.version_info)
print(get_address_overview('1BTCorgHwCg6u2YSAWKgS17qUad6kHmtQW'))
```

is raising this exception on my local installation (I'm using PyCharm)

> 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
> sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\idna.py", line 167, in encode raise UnicodeError("label too long")
> UnicodeError: label too long

while on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@Davide3i/Blockcypher-Test) everything is working flawlessly.

Debugging **idna.py** showed that the 3rd label is the one raising the exception, but I'm struggling to understand why I'm having this issue on my local installation.

[image: idna.py Exception]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A fix for Windows has been made](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/issues/79) in the last release (1.0.80).